# I need an algorithm that resembles the behavior of a for loop reevaluation of the testing condition

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

I am iterating an array of boxes that are placed in a container. For example a container can store level "10" of boxes. if an array is [6, 5, 2]. I will have two containers: one with [6, 2] and one with [5], the array was iterated it grabbed the 6, skipped 5 and grabbed 2. It skipped 5 because 6 + 5 is 11. The container cannot have more than level 10. The skipped 5 is placed in a separated array to be iterated later.

Below I summarize my problem. This is not a working code. I am just demostrating my problem.

```
$boxes = [2, 3, 2, 5, 8, 2, 10, 2, 5, 6]; // my boxes

$separated_boxes = [];
$items = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($boxes); $i++){

 $items[] = $box[$i]; //add box to array

  $result = Class::packBoxes($items) // check if the box(es) can be packed

 //if the current box cannot be packed it is separated
  if($result == false)
  {
     $separated_boxes[] = $box[$i];
  }

   //if the loop reaches the end a new loop should start with the separated boxes

//Apparently I cannot do this because the for conditions are avalidated only once

    if((($i + 1) == count($boxes) && count($separated_boxes) > 0)){

               $itens = [];
                $i = 0;
                $boxes= $separated_boxes;
                $separated_boxes= [];
       }
 }

   packBoxes($boxes)
{
  if(canPack($box)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in term of wrong kind of loop for this. `for`–like loops is typically used to do something for each item in input *once*.

But this is not something that you need. You need to check items in input *repeatedly*, setting them aside and coming back for them, until all of them are distributed into containers.

There are a lot of ways to write this (loop, iterator, recursive function, object with logic...). In terms of loop you can try a `do-while` one like this:

```php
do {

  // take items out of $boxes until you fill <=10 units container

} while( ! empty( $boxes ) );
```